# Playn text wrapping and style issue

Tags: styles, playn

As in Effect.shadow() is deprecated in PlayN1.3.So i had something like this before :

```
TextFormat textFormat = new TextFormat(myFont, textWidth, Alignment.LEFT, colorCode, Effect.shadow(-16777216, shadowX, shadowY));
```

So i changed it to this :

```
TextFormat textFormat = new TextFormat();
textFormat.withFont(myFont);
textFormat.withWrapping(textWidth, Alignment.LEFT);
```

I dont want shadow now.It's ok but i did not get previous like result.Hold on.dont think now.Then i changed this code to this:

```
TextFormat textFormat = new TextFormat().withFont(myFont).withWrapping(textWidth, Alignment.LEFT);
```

It gives me result as previous except shadow which i dont care now.If i am not wrong this is one line representation of above code.Is not it?
So why it worked and above code did not.Any conceptual difference is there? Anyone can explain please!

//note: dont worry about variables(textWidth,myFont)they are nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TextFormat objects are immutable. When you call textFormat.withFont(myFont) that returns a *new* TextFormat instance, which the code above is throwing away. If you want the first code to work you need to write it like this:

```
TextFormat format = new TextFormat();
format = format.withFont(myFont);
format = format.withWrapping(textWidth, Alignment.LEFT);
```